# Añadir o quitar clase según si un icono está clicado o no

Tags: javascript, menu

Quiero hacer un menú que al principio muestre una frase y el icono de abrir, y al hacerle clic, se muestre el menú y el icono para cerrarlo (y volver a la frase).

He conseguido que el icono cambie según si hemos click o no e inicialmente se ve el texto y el boton para abrir, pero no consigo que al hacer clic, desaparezca el texto y aparezca el menú.

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <!--ICONO MENU ABRIR onclick="toggleMenu()"-->
    <div class="menu-icon" >
      <img src="https://andalopa.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/i-toggle.png" alt="Icono del menú" width="24" height="24">
    </div>
        <!--ICONO MENU CERRAR
    <div class="menu-icon-close">
        <img src="https://andalopa.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/close-menu-icon.svg" alt="Icono del menú cerrar" width="24" height="24">
    </div>-->
    <!--FRASE MENU-->
    <p class="menu-text">
      CELEBRANDO <span id="selected-word">los</span> PEQUEÑOS DETALLES
    </p>
    <!--ELEMENTOS MENU-->
    <ul class="menu-items cerrado">
      <li><a href="https://www.andalopa.com/inicio" onclick="setActiveItem(event, 0)">INICIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.andalopa.com/about" onclick="setActiveItem(event, 1)">CONÓCEME</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.andalopa.com/portfolio" onclick="setActiveItem(event, 2)">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.andalopa.com/contacto" onclick="ActiveItem(event, 3)">CONTACTO</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <script>

    //Menu
    const menuItems = document.querySelector('.menu-items');
    //Texto
    const menuText = document.querySelector('.menu-text');

    //Boton abrir y boton cerrar
    const menuIcons = {
        abrir:'<img src="https://andalopa.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/i-toggle.png" alt="Icono del menú" width="24" height="24">',
        cerrar:'<img src="https://andalopa.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/close-menu-icon.svg" alt="Icono del menú cerrar" width="24" height="24">'
    };

    //Funcion para que la funcion toggleMenu se ejecute al clicar boton abrir
    function addListeners(){
        //Le damos toggle buton al boton de abrir
        const toggleButton = document.querySelector(".menu-icon");
        //Cuando hacemos clic en ese boton se activa esa funcion
        toggleButton.addEventListener("click",toggleMenu);
    }

    function toggleMenu(){
        const menuText = document.querySelector('.menu-text');
        const toggleButton = document.querySelector(".menu-icon");

        //El boton que abre, tiene la clase CSS open, con esta clase se muestra o no el icono de menu
        toggleButton.classList.toggle("open");

        //Para la constante con el menu abierto, significa que el boton tienen la clase open
        const isMenuOpen = toggleButton.classList.contains("open");

        //Si esta el menu abierto, mostrar cerrar, si no está abierto, mostrar abrir
        toggleButton.innerHTML = isMenuOpen ? menuIcons.cerrar : menuIcons.abrir;
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addListeners);
```

Comment: ¿Lo que estás buscando es ocultar o mostrar el menú según sea el caso?

Answer (score 0):

Con un poco de CSS lo consigues:

Esconde cualquier hermano de `.menu-icon` que sea de la clase `.menu-items`

```
.menu-icon ~ .menu-items {
  display:none;
}
```

Luego al hacer click al botón añades la clase `open` a `.menu-icon`, entonces necesitas: Mostrar cualquier hermano de clase `.menu-icon.open` que sea de la clase `.menu-items`

```
.menu-icon.open ~ .menu-items {
  display:unset;
}
```

Luego para el caso de `.menu-text` es lo inverso, muestras cuando no está la clase `.open` y lo escondes en caso contrario.

Aquí una Demo:

```js
    //Menu
    const menuItems = document.querySelector('.menu-items');
    //Texto
    const menuText = document.querySelector('.menu-text');

    //Boton abrir y boton cerrar
    const menuIcons = {
        abrir:'<img src="https://andalopa.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/i-toggle.png" alt="Icono del menú" width="24" height="24">',
        cerrar:'<img src="https://andalopa.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/close-menu-icon.svg" alt="Icono del menú cerrar" width="24" height="24">'
    };

    //Funcion para que la funcion toggleMenu se ejecute al clicar boton abrir
    function addListeners(){
        //Le damos toggle buton al boton de abrir
        const toggleButton = document.querySelector(".menu-icon");
        //Cuando hacemos clic en ese boton se activa esa funcion
        toggleButton.addEventListener("click",toggleMenu);
    }

    function toggleMenu(){
        const menuText = document.querySelector('.menu-text');
        const toggleButton = document.querySelector(".menu-icon");

        //El boton que abre, tiene la clase CSS open, con esta clase se muestra o no el icono de menu
        toggleButton.classList.toggle("open");

        //Para la constante con el menu abierto, significa que el boton tienen la clase open
        const isMenuOpen = toggleButton.classList.contains("open");

        //Si esta el menu abierto, mostrar cerrar, si no está abierto, mostrar abrir
        toggleButton.innerHTML = isMenuOpen ? menuIcons.cerrar : menuIcons.abrir;
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addListeners);
```

```css
.menu-icon ~ .menu-items {
  display:none;
}

.menu-icon ~ .menu-text {
  display:unset;
}

.menu-icon.open ~ .menu-items {
  display:unset;
}
.menu-icon.open ~ .menu-text  {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
  <nav>
    <!--ICONO MENU ABRIR onclick="toggleMenu()"-->
    <div class="menu-icon" >
      <img src="https://andalopa.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/i-toggle.png" alt="Icono del menú" width="24" height="24">
    </div>
        <!--ICONO MENU CERRAR
    <div class="menu-icon-close">
        <img src="https://andalopa.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/close-menu-icon.svg" alt="Icono del menú cerrar" width="24" height="24">
    </div>-->
    <!--FRASE MENU-->
    <p class="menu-text">
      CELEBRANDO <span id="selected-word">los</span> PEQUEÑOS DETALLES
    </p>
    <!--ELEMENTOS MENU-->
    <ul class="menu-items cerrado">
      <li><a href="https://www.andalopa.com/inicio" onclick="setActiveItem(event, 0)">INICIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.andalopa.com/about" onclick="setActiveItem(event, 1)">CONÓCEME</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.andalopa.com/portfolio" onclick="setActiveItem(event, 2)">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.andalopa.com/contacto" onclick="ActiveItem(event, 3)">CONTACTO</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder tan rápido!! Funciona perfectamente, lo malo es que quería que el menú tuviera display:flex para que se viera en una linea. Al usar display:unset, no puedo modificar esto